# community detection on edges with weights on spark (louvain)

Tags: spark-graphx

I would like to use Spark/graphx implementation of Louvain modularity algorithm.
https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity

1. Is there a way to apply it on a graph with weighted edges?
2. It seems that an input file can contain 2 or 3 columns. If it is 2,
   then the first one is the source and the second is the destination.
   What is the third column? Weights?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply it to weighted graphs and the third column is the edge weight.

[Here](http://sotera.github.io/distributed-graph-analytics/FAQ/#how-data) you have a description of the expected data format.